# Returning to a previous work directory (shell terminal)

Tags: linux, terminal, cd

I know about cd - 
and pushd commands. 
what i am looking for is something could be described as the following:

1- save what pwd command return to you in some kind of variable (say X)

2- go to whatever other directories you want to visit

3- once done , cd X (go back to the original working directory)

Thanks Community for your help and for the amazing tips i find here :)

Cheers, 
Udai

Comment: "I know about forks, but I need something where I can 1) stab it into a piece of food, 2) bring to mouth, and then 3) take it off with my lips so I can eat it." Dude, `pushd`/`popd` do exactly what you're describing. If not, you have to describe what they're not doing that you need.

Comment: the thing that pushd queue get crowded pretty fast for me and i get lost where is my working directory, i guess i am not used to the pushd command pretty well 
and btw :looooool .. hilarious comment

Answer (score 0):

Amadan is correct, however if you're really dead-set on it, you can do

```
alias back='cd '`pwd`
```

Then do your browsing, then type `back` to come back to the directory you ran `alias` in.

Edit: Slightly more sophisticated idea: add

```
alias save=`alias back="cd $PWD"`
```

to your ~/.bashrc. Then, you can type `save` in a directory, browse, then `back` will bring you back to the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily exactly as you say, with variables. Bonus, you can access your files from elsewhere:

```
GOLDMINE=`pwd`
cd /tmp/casino
play
echo "oops, forgot my wallet"
cat $GOLDMINE/wallet
cd /tmp/bedroom
play harder
echo "gotta go back to work"
cd $GOLDMINE
```

(well, actually I'd probably use something short like `$D`, but you get the gist)